# generation of a graphic chart using spring boot thymleaf

Tags: spring, charts, highcharts, spring-thymeleaf

I have a problem with graphic chart generation in a pdf report , I'm creating a pdf report with simple data and I want to add a summary graphic chart using spring boot and thymleaf, the problem is that the part where I must have the graphic chart is empty.

I tried with Google charts and HighCharts API, but still the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Software developer, Could you add more details about the problem? It would be great if you could show which data structure is delivered to the chart in a simple live example. You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , i'm trying to generate a pdf report using spring boot and thymleaf , the problem isthat simply the document in the part where the graph should have had it was blank , HTML web page is successfully displayed, but when inserted in Thymeleaf despite being in .HTML when converting to PDF, it is blank.  it give me alwayes the some error "No worker found for tag script"  , have you got any suggestion to to resolve this problem please !

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but unfortunately, I am unable to help you. I can help you only with JS and Highcharts part. Please try to extract the problem. You have the same issue with Highcharts and Goggle charts, so it means that the problem is related to spring boot or thymleaf.